# Using break for nested for loop

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to apply three levels of filtering on `record`.

1. `rec` in cname. `rec` is string of >2 words, so I want to consider all ngram of `rec` to be checked in `record`

   i. if `gram` matches into `record` increment `filter_company_level` and write it to file
2. 2nd Filter on record is for each value `value` in `self.keyword_material_info` list.

   i. if `value` matches into `record` increment `filter_with_material_info` and write it to file
3. 3rd filter is for `item` in `self.keyword_bse_list` .

   i. if `item` matches into `record` increment `filter_with_keyword_info` and write it to file

   ii. Now move to next record if inner most filter is present.

I have written these code, does it satisfy above conditions, or is there any bug? None of them give error but want to make sure that logic is correct.

```
        for record in fetch_record:
            total += 1
            for rec in cname:
                try:
                    c_ngram = self.get_ngrams(rec['company_name'])
                    for gram in c_ngram:
                        if gram.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                            filter_company_level += 1
                            # print "Matched based on company name : ", record['article_link']
                            company_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+'\n')
                            for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                                if value.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                    filter_with_material_info += 1
                                    materialinfo_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+' - '+value+'\n')
                                    for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                                        if item.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                            filter_with_keyword_info += 1
                                            keyword_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+" - "+value+' - '+item+'\n')
                                            print record['article_link']
                                            print value
                                            print item
                                            break
                                    break
                            # break
                            raise GetOutOfLoop
                except GetOutOfLoop:
                    break
```

Or this one is correct?

```
        for record in fetch_record:
            total += 1
            for rec in cname:
                try:
                    c_ngram = self.get_ngrams(rec['company_name'])
                    for gram in c_ngram:
                        if gram.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                            filter_company_level += 1
                            # print "Matched based on company name : ", record['article_link']
                            company_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+'\n')
                            for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                                if value.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                    filter_with_material_info += 1
                                    materialinfo_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+' - '+value+'\n')
                                    flag_keyword = 0
                                    for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                                        if item.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                            filter_with_keyword_info += 1
                                            keyword_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+" - "+value+' - '+item+'\n')
                                            print record['article_link']
                                            print value
                                            print item
                                            flag_keyword = 1
                                            break
                                    if flag_keyword == 1:
                                        break
                            # break
                            if flag_keyword == 1:
                                raise GetOutOfLoop
                except GetOutOfLoop:
                    break
```

Comment: "does it satisfy above conditions" Did you test them both? How? What was the result?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d go with the review of the second version of the code since it’s the same as the first one with the addition of the `flag_keyword` logic. If you want guidance on how to produce code matching requirements or how to debug your code, you’d be better of asking on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

A little bit on logic, though: since you want to move to the next record when the innermost filter validates your `flag_keyword` value should be reset at each iteration of the outermost loop. Preferably as the first condition after `for record in fetch_record`. If your dataset makes it through the whole `for` loop without entering the last `if`, then your

```
if flag_keyword == 1:
    raise GetOutOfLoop
```

will raise `NameError: name 'flag_keyword' is not defined`.

You are using the flag to run some code only if you broke out of a loop. Note, however, that if you change the logic a bit and want to run some code only if you **didn't** broke the loop you can use a [`for ... else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct.

Now let’s go to the code:

- Your `GetOutOfLoop` exception's only purpose is to let you break out of the outermost loop only if you broke from the innermost one (i.e. your innermost filter validates). The same thing you are doing with your `flag_keyword` at a deeper nesting level. Get consistent: don't mix implementations for similar tasks. There is an other approach if you read on but I’d raise the exception in replacement of the innermost `break` to avoid all your '`break` if I broke' logic because:
- You have too much nesting levels, it makes code harder to read and follow. Remember that:

  ```
  for value in data:
      if is_valid(value):
          do_stuff()
  ```

  can also be written:

  ```
  for value in data:
      if not is_valid(value):
          continue
      do_stuff()
  ```

  when `do_stuff` is composed of nested loops, it can save on indentation levels. However, you can get rid of these test by using generators:

  ```
  for value in (v for v in data if is_valid(v)):
      do_stuff()
  ```
- Even if the purpose of the `for ... else` loop is to run some code only if you didn't `break` out of the loop, you can use it to run some code only if you **did** `break`. The general approach is:

  ```
  for value in data:
      # some code
  else:
      do_stuff_if_no_break()
  ```

  But for your use case, since you are within loops each time, you can change it to:

  ```
  for value in data:
      # some code
  else:
      continue
  do_stuff_if_break()
  ```
- You check for various things `in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower()` but you are building this string a large number of times. It is best, performance-wise, to build it once as soon as you get the `record` dictionary. Speaking of dictionary, you can improve the syntax a bit:

  ```
  u'{title} {description}'.format(**record).lower()
  ```
- You use `lower` on each items of your intermediate iterables (`self.keyword_material_info`, `self.keyword_bse_list` and the one returned by `self.get_ngrams()`). Can't you build those iterables with already formatted strings?

The code would become:

```
for record in fetch_record:
    search = u'{title} {description}'.format(**record).lower()
    total += 1
    for rec in cname:
        c_ngram = self.get_ngrams(rec['company_name'])
        # assuming c_ngrams contains items already formatted with .lower()+' '
        for gram in (g for g in c_ngram if g in search):
            filter_company_level += 1
            # print "Matched based on company name : ", record['article_link']
            company_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+'\n')
            # assuming keyword_material_info contains items already formatted with .lower()+' '
            for value in (v for v in self.keyword_material_info if v in search):
                filter_with_material_info += 1
                materialinfo_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+' - '+value+'\n')
                # assuming keyword_bse_list contains items already formatted with .lower()+' '
                for item in (i for i in self.keyword_bse_list if i in search):
                    filter_with_keyword_info += 1
                    keyword_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+" - "+value+' - '+item+'\n')
                    print record['article_link']
                    print value
                    print item
                    break
                else:
                    # skip the next break if we didn't found an <item> matching <search>
                    continue
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            continue
        break
```

However I’m a little bit worried on the nesting of your loops. Since neither `self.keyword_material_info` nor `self.keyword_bse_list` seems to depend on `gram`... They might be modified by the call of `self.get_ngrams()` but I can't verify.

One last note, that I didn’t try to enforce while re-writting your code: you may want to improve your variable naming. `item` or `value` does not carry much information, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Large `try` blocks are bad, avoid them at all costs. If you want a way to immediately break out of nested `for` loops, wrap the outermost loop in a function and then use `return`.

```
def my_nested_loops():
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            for k in range(10):
                for l in range(10):
                    for m in range(10):
                        if done:
                            return val
                else:
                    if sorta_done:
                        return val
    # No value found
    return False or None or raise SomeError
```

As you can see, you could `return` from any level, at any point. If you come across errors or determine that there's no valid result, then you can `return False` or `None` or `raise SomeError` if you need to. Of course this is in addition to Mathias's suggestions about using `continue`. As much as possible, try avoiding nesting to begin with but there are better ways to handle it if you have no choice.

Don't use `flag_keyword = 1` as a flag. Use booleans for flags, you can set them just as easily, and use `if flag_keyword` as your test. Though as far as I can see, you could instead of doing any of that have a `return` when you want to set your flag.

Comment: Damn, I knew there should be something way cleaner than my `else: continue` but couldn't think of it out of OP's code…